# Get ID of last inserted document in a mongoDB w/ Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there an easy way to get the ID (ObjectID) of the last inserted document of a mongoDB instance using the Java driver?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

I just realized you can do this:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject( "name", "Matt" );
collection.insert( doc );
ObjectId id = (ObjectId)doc.get( "_id" );
```

Comment: Is it outdated?

Comment: @Stu_Dent No, but if your insertOne() has void return type, you are probably using the outdated mongodb driver.  "mongo-java-driver"/"mongodb-driver" is legacy.  You should probably be using  " mongodb-driver-sync" https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb

Answer (score 15):

To avoid casting from `Object` to `ObjectId`, given a `com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection collection` and a `org.bson.Document doc`, you can do the following:

```
collection.insert(doc);
ObjectId id = doc.getObjectId("_id");
```

Comment: I'm assuming this became possible in the 3.x java driver?

Answer (score 13):

It's safe to do

```
doc.set("_id", new ObjectId())
```

if you look at driver code

```
if ( ensureID && id == null ){
    id = ObjectId.get();
    jo.put( "_id" , id );       
}

public static ObjectId get(){
    return new ObjectId();
}
```

Comment: did you mean to say `it's save to do` or `it's safe to do`?

Comment: For some reason, in MongoDB 2.2.2 (as opposed to earlier when I was on 2.2.0) and with the Java driver 2.10.1, the code in the answer doesn't work; after I upsert the object into the document, I can't seem to get its _id, even though MongoDB plainly auto-generates ObjectId's. However, your solution of manually creating an ObjectId  does work, and thanks for this option!

Comment: <code>
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId());
    System.out.println("doc.id before: " + doc.get("_id"));
    new Mongo("localhost").getDB("test").getCollection("t").insert(doc);
    System.out.println("doc.id after: " + doc.get("_id")); 
    </code>
this code work well for me, tested on new versions mongo 2.2.2, driver 2.10.1

Answer (score 7):

I do not know about the Java driver but for posterity, the getLastError command can be run to get the _id of a write, even an upsert (as of 1.5.4)

Answer (score 4):

After a document is inserted into the MongoDB collection, the successful insertion should update required fields (viz. _id). You may query the inserted object for the _id.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoTemplate.class has a method

```
protected <T> void doInsert(String collectionName, T objectToSave, MongoWriter<T> writer) {

    assertUpdateableIdIfNotSet(objectToSave);

    initializeVersionProperty(objectToSave);

    maybeEmitEvent(new BeforeConvertEvent<T>(objectToSave, collectionName));

    DBObject dbDoc = toDbObject(objectToSave, writer);

    maybeEmitEvent(new BeforeSaveEvent<T>(objectToSave, dbDoc, collectionName));
    Object id = insertDBObject(collectionName, dbDoc, objectToSave.getClass());

    populateIdIfNecessary(objectToSave, id);
    maybeEmitEvent(new AfterSaveEvent<T>(objectToSave, dbDoc, collectionName));
}
```

and the method will set id for us

```
protected void populateIdIfNecessary(Object savedObject, Object id) {

    if (id == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (savedObject instanceof BasicDBObject) {
        DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) savedObject;
        dbObject.put(ID_FIELD, id);
        return;
    }

    MongoPersistentProperty idProp = getIdPropertyFor(savedObject.getClass());

    if (idProp == null) {
        return;
    }

    ConversionService conversionService = mongoConverter.getConversionService();
    MongoPersistentEntity<?> entity = mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(savedObject.getClass());
    PersistentPropertyAccessor accessor = entity.getPropertyAccessor(savedObject);

    if (accessor.getProperty(idProp) != null) {
        return;
    }

    new ConvertingPropertyAccessor(accessor, conversionService).setProperty(idProp, id);
}
```

we can see if the entity is a sub-class of BasicDBObject,it will set a id for us.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is "No".

What you can do is provide your the `_id` yourself, either manually, or implement the `CollectibleCodec` mechanism (which is exactly what `BasicBDDocument` does). However all these solutions involve generating the ID clientside.

Having said that, I don't think there's any problem with generating the `_id` clientside.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but the current answer is "yes" the _id field of the inserted document is found in the document that's returned by the insert/insertOne methods. This code:

```
 InsertOneResult res =
        client
            .getDatabase(dbName)
            .getCollection(collection)
            .insertOne(new Document().append("name", "matt"));
 System.out.println("acknowledged? " +  res.wasAcknowledged());
 System.out.println("insertedId: " + res.getInsertedId());
 System.out.println("inserted objectId: " + 
            res.getInsertedId().asObjectId().getValue());
```

Yields this:

```
acknowledged? true
insertedId: BsonObjectId{value=65d2b9c9c5a6b405075b3afe}
inserted objectId: 65d2b9c9c5a6b405075b3afe
```

Answer (score -2):

This is insert operation:

```
DBCollection table1 = db.getCollection("Collection name");
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("_id",value);      
document.put("Name", name);
table1.insert(document);
```

After insert u get last inserted id:

```
DBCollection tableDetails = db.getCollection("collection name");
BasicDBObject queryDetails = new BasicDBObject();
queryDetails.put("_id", value);
DBCursor cursorDetails =tableDetails.find(queryDetails);
DBObject oneDetails;
oneDetails=cursorDetails.next();        
String data=oneDetails.get("_id").toString();
System.out.println(data);
```

after getting value convert to inter type.