# Get Mongo db id after insertion in case of POJO class

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I have a POJO class in java

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestModel{
    protected ObjectId id;
    private String name;
}
```

Is there any way to populate id field in case of insertion. [I can see that if I use `Document`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338999/get-id-of-last-inserted-document-in-a-mongodb-w-java-driver), then after insertion I can get objectId by using

```
document.get("_id");
```

So is there any way I can achieve same using custom POJO class.

Comment: You don't. You set the `id` within your class **before** you persist it for saving. See [JAVA-2674](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2674). That's basically intentional design within the driver, and not a bug.